# Import errors in django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am a newbie to django and after going through some `django` tutorial i have started using `django-cms`(I had a requirement to develop a cms site with django-cms).

I have edited the settings file and added all the middlewares,apps that are necessary for `cms`, so everything is going fine and started developing html templates, but sometimes after i restarting the server and getting the below weird errors

**Error_1**

```
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name plugin_pool
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/__init__.py in <module>, line 7
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

**Error_2**

```
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Value:    Reverse for 'pages-root' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py in new_reverse, line 67
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
................
```

These are the two errors i am facing sometimes and don't know why they are encountered because they are appearing suddenly, can i know how to avoid these errors

some of the settings are below

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware', #CMS
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware', #CMS
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware', #CMS
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware', #CMS    
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'reversion',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'cmsplugin_filer_file',
    'cmsplugin_filer_image',
    'cmsplugin_filer_teaser',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms_themes',

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Django 1.4.3 I have had the same problem with this error:

```
ImportError at / - cannot import name plugin_pool
```

after research i have found that simply by updating my django to version 1.4.5
my plugin_pool import error has gone away.